# Gmail - Schedule send

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, gmail-imap, gmail-addons, gmail-contextual-gadgets

I wish gmail gave more Schedule send times by default - not just default

```
Tomorrow morning Mar 24, 8:00 AM
Tomorrow afternoon Mar 24, 1:00 PM
Monday morning Mar 30, 8:00 AM
```

I'd love to have options like

```
in 2 minutes
in 10 minutes 
in 1 hour
in 2 hours
```

in case I realize I need to add something ...

I guess we need to write a browser extension for that

but you never know that's why I'm asking here ...

any advice?

thank you ...